# Is it possible to multiply two numbers together that are expressed in polar form?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there meaning to an expression (r1, theta1 ) ( r2, theta2) in polar form does this have any meaning?   The instructor seems to have converted this expression to (r1cos(theta)1 + r1isintheta1) ( r2cos(theta2) + r2isin(theta2)).

I can use trig identities OK on the last expression and get a complex number but he ends up with ( r1+r2) , theta1 + theta2) .  Does anyone understand what he is doing?

If I start out with complex expression I am OK but this seems to convert from regular polar to complex and back again but I am unclear how this is done and I know very well how to express a complex number in polar form!  I looked at Wiki but they don't combine the concepts into one like this instructor is doing!   He seems to be tossing them as if polar coordinates are the same as complex polar coordinates and I don't see that! Thank you.

Comment: Your instructor has converted polar form into parametric. My thing here is, you are not multiplying just two numbers. You are multiplying two points. What does that mean?

Comment: is there an example of this that you are aware of?

Comment: That depends. Complex numbers can be represented as points in the 2D grid and they can be multiplied.

Comment: The final complex number from multiplication is $(r_1 r_2,\theta_1+\theta_2)$. To check the first part, just use two real numbers, for which $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$